# Insert Into, even if blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a check to see if a file has come in in the past 18 hours.
In the same table, there are checks where the file is always generated. This specific file doesn't always come in.

What I would like to do is have an IF/ELSE in place so if the condition is not met, the field still generated to tell the user the file is not present, rather than there just being no record.

```
DECLARE @BASE varchar(55) = 'BASE5_017_%'

INSERT INTO @TranTable(Inbound,BatchID,Filename,FileDateTime,TotalCount,IsValid)
select top 1 'BASE', BatchID,Filename,FileDateTime,TotalCount,IsValid from TranBatchFile (nolock)
where Filename like @BASE AND FileDateTime >= DATEADD(HH,@TimeD,@Now) order by 1 desc
```

This is what I have. What I like would be:

```
Insert into ....
If this check comes back with something
show the something
else
"nothing here champ, find out what went wrong"
```

Keeping the Inbound field intact, but the rest blank, maybe with the `Filename` field saying find out what went wrong

Comment: I'm confused.  You have to ask the operating system if a file is available, and your code is not doing that.  Is this information reflected in a table?  If so, you need to explain how that works.

Comment: Use an `EXISTS` in the `IF` clause? What logic is `"nothing here champ, find out what went wrong"`? What do you expect to happen there?

Comment: The table output shows the multiple files that are generated via event scheduler (not important). the code above pulls the names and info of the files from `TranBatchFile`. This `BASE` file is not always present, so the output of the table needs to alert the user, rather than not having a record

Comment: Never use `ORDER BY <num>` in production code. For one-off queries it can save some typing but it's a maintenance nightmare. In this case it's an outright mistake since you are ordering by the value `'BASE'`, which is of course no order at all.

Comment: It's for a declared table that gets dropped after the query is run

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant -- the fact is that you now have a `SELECT TOP 1` with a non-deterministic order, meaning you will get any record that matches the `WHERE` -- engine's choice. If you know there cannot or should not be more than one record you can leave out the `TOP 1` and check afterwards; if there might be more records and you really want a specific one, use a meaningful `ORDER BY` (like `ORDER BY FileDateTime DESC`).

Comment: You're not wrong. Resolved that particular issue now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
insert into test
select id, col2 from test where id = 2
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0  
insert into test values(2, 'B')
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f112326ed5ee9d58febb1d3e22d39615)

Comment: Ignore last comment, it was correct, I was changing the wrong field in one of the declares. this works perfectly

Comment: I am happy to help. I have not seen the last comment :)